# converting binary data to audio in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have my server in C# (windows forms) from which I record the sound of the system and send the sound as byte array segment through websocket. I created the client is in flutter to play the data received from the websocket sever,
when I print the data received from the server, it gives me something like this

> [44, 208, 240, 11, 78, 112, 62, 234, 159, 35, 145, 128, 240, 99, 91,
> 123, 252, 181, 56, 44, 222, 214, 137, 206, 45, 55, 59, 114, 199, 206,
> 47, 230, 77, 154, 200, 12, 218, 187, 187, 100, 219, 225, 6, 82, 123,
> 75, 133, 251, 105, 44, 243, 232, 69, 24, 31, 95, 39, 136, 43, 152,
> 121, 233, 56, 22, 197, 141, 44, 213, 47, 182, 77, 59, 171, 201, 37,
> 101, 125, 203, 126, 113, 131, 175, 194, 244, 7, 158, 154, 138, 25,
> 223, 217, 123, 112, 225, 133, 139, 59, 230, 31, 227, 110, 92, 4, 187,
> 187, 99, 222, 217, 173, 153, 185, 54, 145, 63, 128, 102, 34, 148, 64,
> 242, 188, 131, 4, 127, 49, 217, 38, 41, 58, 39, 53, 209, 46, 216, 160,
> 164, 142, 102, 226, 151, 223, 133, 150, 201, 66, 131, 133, 89, 216,
> 69, 174, 181, 117, 114, 23, 188, 73, 1, 180, 156, 179, 254, 119, 219,
> 231, 142, 139, 40, 214, 75, 187, 97, 126, 85, 2, 86, 178, 7, 33, 112,
> 4, 121, 242, 39, 185, 155, 27, 173, 24, 185, 226, 167, 141, 105, 58,
> 104, 202, 47]

and when I print the runtime type of the data the result is

> _uint8arrayView

I have surf the net found nothing in similar to my case in flutter so I don't know what to do again. I want to use [soundpool package](https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool) or [AssetAudioPlayer package](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) to play it. Any ideas will be well appreciated. Thanks in advance!.

Here is the main logic of what I have done so far in flutter

```
  Future client() async {
    Random r = new Random();
    String key = base64.encode(List<int>.generate(8, (_) => r.nextInt(255)));

    HttpClient client = HttpClient(/* optional security context here */);
    Uri uri = new Uri(
        scheme: "http",
        host: _controller.text.trim(),
        port: int.parse("5970", radix: 10),
        path: "");
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(uri);
    // HttpClientRequest request = await client.get(
    //     'ws://${_controller.text.trim()}',
    //     int.parse("5970", radix: 10),
    //     'chat'); // form the correct url here
    request.headers.add('Connection', 'upgrade');
    request.headers.add('Upgrade', 'websocket');
    request.headers
        .add('sec-websocket-version', '13'); // insert the correct version here
    request.headers.add('sec-websocket-key', key);

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    // todo check the status code, key etc
    Socket socket = await response.detachSocket();

    WebSocket ws = WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket(
      socket,
      serverSide: false,
    );
    ws.listen(
      (event) {
        connected = true;
        var bytes = File.fromRawPath(event);

        var s = openBytesStream(event);

        //streamController.addStream(event);
        //stream(s);
        print(event.runtimeType);

        //soudpool();
      },
      onError: (error) {
        connected = false;
      },
      onDone: () {
        connected = false;
      },
      cancelOnError: false,
    );
  }


  final assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

  Future stream(String url) async {
    try {
      await assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Audio.liveStream(url),
        showNotification: true,
        autoStart: true,
      );
    } catch (t) {
      //stream unreachable
      print(t);
    }
  }

  Future<void> soudpool(Uint8List soundData) async {
    Soundpool pool = Soundpool(streamType: StreamType.notification);

    int soundId = await pool.loadAndPlayUint8List(soundData);

    int streamId = await pool.play(soundId);
  }
```

Comment: I don't have a code example ready but I'm researching the same question. You could use the audiofileplayer package and use the `loadFromByteData` method from within a StreamBuilder.